# http.rb: how to disable ssl verification

Tags: ruby, http.rb

SSL validation fails on some HTTP calls: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed`

However we want those requests to be made anyway, how to force http.rb to proceed anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a ssl_context VERIFY_NONE to your request:

```
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
HTTP.get(url, ssl_context: ssl_context)
```